# Ajax comment System not working properly when having multiple forms

Tags: php, html, ajax

So i am doing this website for a class and i need to use ajax for the comment system.So far i manged to user JavaScript and what not to save to the database but when i press submit it is not showing the comment.

Also another problem i am having is when i have lets say 2 posts it will generate 2 forms. 1 of the forms wont work with the ajax and wont even insert into the database.

**index.php Code**

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="comments.js"></script>
    <?php 
        require_once("menu.php");

        $connection = connectToMySQL();


        $selectPostQuery = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `tblposts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER BY id DESC";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$selectPostQuery)
            or die("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $postid = $row['ID'];

    ?>
            <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="titlecontainer">
            <h1><?php echo $row['Title']?></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="textcontainer">
            <?php echo $row['Content']?>
            </div>
    <?php
            if (!empty($row['ImagePath'])) #This will check if there is an path in the textfield
            {
    ?>
                <div class="imagecontainer">
                <img src="images/<?php echo "$row[ImagePath]"; ?>" alt="Article Image">
                </div>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
            <div class="timestampcontainer">
            <b>Date posted :</b><?php echo $row['TimeStamp']?>
            <b>Author :</b> Admin
            </div>
    <?php
            #Selecting comments corresponding to the post
            $selectCommentQuery = "SELECT * FROM `tblcomments` LEFT JOIN `tblusers` ON tblcomments.userID = tblusers.ID WHERE tblcomments.PostID ='$postid'";

            $commentResult = mysqli_query($connection,$selectCommentQuery)
                or die ("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

            #renderinf the comments
            while ($commentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentResult)) 
            {
    ?>
                <div class="commentcontainer">
                <div class="commentusername"><h1>Username :<?php echo $commentRow['Username']?></h1></div>
                <div class="commentcontent"><?php echo $commentRow['Content']?></div>
                <div class="commenttimestamp"><?php echo $commentRow['Timestamp']?></div>
                </div>
    <?php
            }


            if (!empty($_SESSION['userID']) ) 
            {
    ?>
                <form method="POST" class="post-frm" id="form">
                <label>New Comment</label>
                <textarea id="comment" name="comment"> </textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $postid ?>">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name ="submit" class="button"/>
                </form>
    <?php
            }
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<br /> <br /><br />"; 
        }
     require_once("footer.php") ?>
```

**Javascript comment for  ajax.**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var form = $('#form');
        var submit = $('#submit');

        form.on('submit',function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            //send ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_comment.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: form.serialize(), //form serialize data
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //Changeing submit button value text and disableing it
                    submit.val('Submiting ....').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
                    $('.comment-block').append(item);

                    // reset form and button
                    form.trigger('reset');
                    submit.val('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                },
                error: function(e)
                {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**AJAX PHP page**

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])):

        session_start();
        include('connection.php');
        $connection = connectToMySQL();

            $userId = $_SESSION['userID'];
            $postId = $_POST['postid'];
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];

            $insertCommentQuery = "INSERT INTO `tblcomments`       (`Content`,`UserID`,`PostID`,`Timestamp`) VALUES ('$comment','$userId','$postId',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$insertCommentQuery);


    ?>

     <div class="commentcontainer">
     <div class="commentusername"><h1>Username :This is atest</h1></div>
     <div class="commentcontent">This is a test</div>
     <div class="commenttimestamp">Test</div>
     </div>

   <?php
    connectToMySQL(0);
   endif?>
```

Comment: I think you are trying to append the new HTML returned by AJAX to `.comment-block` here like `$('.comment-block').append(item);` but I don't see any `.comment-block` in your `index.php`

Comment: Ohh thank you very much! but i am still having the problem when i have different forms.Meaning only one form works with ajax the other one does not

Comment: Your Ajax code is a bit messy. Sorry no offense but try changing `data: form.serialize()` to `data: $(this).serialize()`

Comment: None taken i know it is. Never done AJAX before so dont rly know i am doing :/
Now it geitng all message up for exmaple if i give the comment to form 1 it goes to form two and if i give comment to form two it goes to form 1

Comment: Try to change your ajax code to the following answer. Hopefully it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to your index.php

```
...
  #renderinf the comments
   echo '<div class="comment-block_' . $postid .'">';
        while ($commentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentResult)) 
        {
?>
            <div class="commentcontainer">
            <div class="commentusername"><h1>Username :<?php echo $commentRow['Username']?></h1></div>
            <div class="commentcontent"><?php echo $commentRow['Content']?></div>
            <div class="commenttimestamp"><?php echo $commentRow['Timestamp']?></div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
  echo '</div>';
...
```

Changes to AJAX PHP PAGE

```
 <?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])):

    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    $connection = connectToMySQL();

        $userId = $_SESSION['userID'];
        $postId = $_POST['postid'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        $insertCommentQuery = "INSERT INTO `tblcomments` 
                               (`Content`,`UserID`,`PostID`,`Timestamp`) 
                              VALUES (
                                 '$comment','$userId','$postId',
                                  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$insertCommentQuery);


$obj = array();

$obj['id'] = $postId;
$obj['html'] = '<div class="commentcontainer">
                    <div class="commentusername"><h1>Username :This is atest</h1></div>
                    <div class="commentcontent">This is a test</div>
                    <div class="commenttimestamp">Test</div>
               </div>';
echo json_encode($obj);

    connectToMySQL(0);
   endif?>
```

And your AJAX

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#submit').on('click',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        //send ajax request
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_comment.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(form).serialize(), //form serialize data
            beforeSend: function(){
                //Changeing submit button value text and disableing it
                $(this).val('Submiting ....').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                var item = $(data.html).hide().fadeIn(800);
                $('.comment-block_' + data.id).append(item);

                // reset form and button
                $(form).trigger('reset');
                $(this).val('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            error: function(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No sorry, still the same problem :(
Which is the following:
I have two post showing in the index.php and when i hadd a comment to the first one the comment goes to the last one and when i try to insert a comment on the last one it just refershes the page.

Comment: Can you please check if the `$postId` variable in your inde.php brings the right Post ID?

Comment: It is yes because when the comment is insert into the database it insert the right postid.

Comment: Oh yes then you need to modify the `success:` part of the ajax and a bit of change in the ajax_php page

Comment: What kind of change? im sorry i know i am geting a bit spoon feed.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Hopefully it should solve the issue.

Comment: Close! Now when i try to comment on the first post it work perfectly.
But when i try to post on the second post it just refershes the page

Comment: Can you check the console when it refreshes the page. There must be some javascript error causing it to avoid ajax and refresh

Comment: Ermm... strange. Ok can you change `$('#submit').on('click',function(e) {` to `$(document).on('click','#submit',function(e) {` in your jquery.

Comment: Yes perfect! it works, thank you very much. ill make sure i understand every single line now :)